# Handle files passed as arguments on the command line in a Gjs Gtk.Application

Tags: javascript, gtk, gtk3, gjs

I am trying to write a GNOME GTK3 application using [Gjs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Gjs) which [handles files passed as command line arguments](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication#Dealing_with_the_command_line). In order to do so I connect the `open` signal of the `Gtk.Application` and set the `Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_OPEN` flag:

```
#!/usr/bin/gjs

const Gio = imports.gi.Gio
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk
const Lang = imports.lang

const MyApplication = new Lang.Class({
  Name: 'MyApplication',

  _init: function() {
    this.application = new Gtk.Application({
      application_id: 'com.example.my-application',
      flags: Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_OPEN
    })

    this.application.connect('startup', this._onStartup.bind(this))
    this.application.connect('open', this._onOpen.bind(this))
    this.application.connect('activate', this._onActivate.bind(this))
  },

  _onStartup: function() {
    log('starting application')
  },

  _onOpen: function(application, files) {
    log('opening ' + files.length + ' files')
    this._onStartup()
  },

  _onActivate: function() {
    log('activating application')
  }
})

let app = new MyApplication()
app.application.run(ARGV)
```

When I run the program with a file argument I expect `_onOpen` to be called with the `GFile` passed in. But instead `_onActivate` is called, like if I'd run it without any file arguments:

```
$ ./open-files.js open-files.js 
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: starting application
Gjs-Message: JS LOG: activating application
```

I am running gjs@1.44.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a discrepancy in how GJS's `ARGV` is defined, relative to the conventions in other languages. In, for example, C, `argv[0]` is the name of the program, and the first argument starts at `argv[1]`. In GJS, the name of the program is `System.programInvocationName`, and the first argument is `ARGV[0]`.

Unfortunately, being part of a C library, `Gtk.Application` expects you to pass in arguments according to the C convention. You can do this:

```
ARGV.unshift(System.programInvocationName);
```

What was happening was that `./open-files.js open-files.js` was putting `['open-files.js']` as `ARGV`, which `Gtk.Application` was interpreting as the name of the program, with no other arguments. If you'd run the program with two file arguments, you would have seen that it "opened" only the second file.

**PS.** Unfortunately there seems to be a bug in GJS 1.44 that prevents the `open` signal from working correctly. For now, I'd suggest working around the problem by subclassing `Gtk.Application` instead of proxying it. Your program would look like this:

```
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk
const Lang = imports.lang
const System = imports.system

const MyApplication = new Lang.Class({
  Name: 'MyApplication',
  Extends: Gtk.Application,

  _init: function(props={}) {
    this.parent(props)
  },

  vfunc_startup: function() {
    log('starting application')
    this.parent()
  },

  vfunc_open: function(files, hint) {
    log('opening ' + files.length + ' files')
  },

  vfunc_activate: function() {
    log('activating application')
    this.parent()
  }
})

let app = new MyApplication({
  application_id: 'com.example.my-application',
  flags: Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_OPEN
})
ARGV.unshift(System.programInvocationName)
app.run(ARGV)
```

Comment: As of now, has the bug you mentioned been fixed? What would be the now-correct GJS implementation of the `open()` virtual function in order to get the arguments? I'm strugging to find the relevant documentation (in JS, that is)

Comment: I don't remember the bug, but the OP's example works so I assume it's been fixed.